# Add Maven repositories for all projects in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, repository

There is a remote Maven repository (http://clojars.org/repo) that I would like to use in multiple different projects in Eclipse.

I'm using Eclipse Indigo 3.7.1.

I believe I could add it as a repository to each project's individual pom.xml, but this seems a somewhat cumbersome approach.

Is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add it in the settings.xml for your user (at C:\Documents and Settings\username.m2 on Win XP or C:\Users\username.m2 on Win Vista/7 or /home/username/.m2 on Linux) or the global settings.xml of your Maven installation ([see the doc of Maven](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Repositories))

If you have multiple users, where you want to do that, it would be easier to setup an own enterprise repository (like [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/) or [Archiva](http://archiva.apache.org/)) and add the clojars repository as a proxy.

Answer (score 2):

Put them into the `settings.xml`. But you need to do that on every machine where you intend to do builds.